# I have a problem with the surv() function

Tags: r, numeric, survival-analysis

I have two variables, V006 and V008, where V006 is time and V008 indicates whether or not an event occurs. I understand that the Surv() function requires the values of V008 to be 0s (censored) or 1s (event). When I use the following formulas, they tell me they are identical:

```
a<- with(data2, Surv(V006, as.numeric(V008)-1))
b<- with(data2, Surv(V006, as.numeric(V008)))
identical(a,b) =TRUE,
```

and, subsequently, when I use

```
ggsurvplot(survfit(a~ 1, data = data2), 
conf.int = TRUE,
censor = TRUE, surv.median.line = "hv", ggtheme = theme_bw(),
pval = FALSE,
risk.table = TRUE,
tables.theme = theme_survminer(),
break.x.by =10,
font.tickslab=12,
font.x=14,
font.y=14,
xlab="Days",
ylab="X",
palette = "black",
title= "X"),
```

both graphs come out exactly the same

How can this happen? Surv() should, in the first case, when I only put (as.numeric(data2$V008)), which converts NOs and YEs into 1s and 2s, give me different results than when I use as.numeric(data2$V008)-1. Can anyone help me?

Extra:

```
    > table(data2$V008)
 No Yes 
173  40 
    > table(as.numeric(data2$V008))
  1   2 
173  40 
    > table(as.numeric(data2$V008)-1)
  0   1 
173  40
```

Comment: please read the documentation: `?Surv event 
The status indicator, normally 0=alive, 1=dead. Other choices are TRUE/FALSE (TRUE = death) or 1/2 (2=death)`